# Unmarshalling of xml file

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have class as this one below :

```
public class Test {
    private String name;
    private String surname;

...getters/setters
}
```

I have xml such as this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<tests>
  <test>
    <surname>Surname</surname>
    <name>Person22</name>
  </test>
  <test>
    <surname>Surname 2</surname>
    <name>Person12</name>
  </test>
</tests>
```

When I try to unmarshall to my object :

```
Unmarshaller um = jc.createUnmarshaller();
Test myJAXBObject = (Test) um.unmarshal(new java.io.FileInputStream( "src/main/resources/test.xml" ));
```

I get this exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"tests"). Expected elements are <{}test>
```

How can I unmarshal list of objects? Is it possible without having to create some wrapper object?

Comment: Seems the subject is not inline with the problem described above!

Comment: What does your question have to do with your title (*"Sort map in Java"*)? Where's the map? "Sort" how?

Comment: Actually you need class `Tests`: `public class Tests { ... private List<Test> tests; ... }`

Comment: I'm sorry about missleading subject, I had some notes in my todo file. One of which was to ask this question, copied the wrong title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you are using JaxB, if that is required then my answer is probably irrelevant but thought I would mention it.

You could look at [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html) which allows you set set 'aliases' for the nodes. So you could add an alias which would treat "tests" as a `java.util.List`. That way you don't need to create a `Tests` object.

Example:

```
XStream xstream = new XStream();
xstream.alias("test", Test.class);
xstream.alias("tests", java.util.List.class);

List<Test> tests = (List<Test>)xstream.fromXML(new java.io.FileInputStream( "src/main/resources/test.xml" ));
```

Answer (score 2):

Create an additional Class Tests that contains a list of Test objects.

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Tests 
{
    @XmlElement(name = "test")
    List<Test> tests = new ArrayList<Test>();

    public List<Test> getTests() {
        return tests;
    }
}
```

Then unmarshall the xml into the Tests object:

```
Unmarshaller um = jc.createUnmarshaller();
Tests myJAXBObject = (Tests) um.unmarshal(new java.io.FileInputStream("src/main/resources/test.xml" ));
```

Then you can obtain your desired Test objects using:

```
List<Test> tests = Tests.getTests();
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make a class that has a list of `Test` (`Tests`) for the unmarshalling to work - otherwise it will try to unmarshal the root element (`tests`) into a `Test` which it is not. For more info see [this](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/java/jaxb/jaxb-marshalling-and-unmarshalling-list-of-objects/).